# A problem with random number generation

Tags: c++, random

I am taking a course on programming, and we're using C++.
We had an assignment where, at some point, we needed to code a function that would return a random number in an [upper, lower] interval. I used the following:

```
lower + (int) (upper * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)));
```

I did not forget to change `srand` by using `srand((unsigned int) time(0))`.

However, I get the same value every time! I asked my professor for help and he, after some investigation, found out that the first number generated by `rand()` isn't that random... The higher order bits remained unchanged, and since this implementation uses them, the end result isn't quite what I expected.

Is there a more elegant, yet simple solution than to discard the first value or use remainders to achieve what I want?

Thanks a lot for your attention!

~Francisco

EDIT: Thank you all for your input. I had no idea `rand()` was such a sucky RNG :P

Comment: Isn't `rand()` obsolete?  I thought everyone is supposed to use `random()` these days.

Comment: What's wrong with

`lower + rand() % (upper - lower + 1)`? Why don't you want to use remainders?

Comment: Just chiming in that I've noticed this too. If you actually just print out the first rand() each time you find that it isn't exactly the same, but the numbers are all fairly close together. For instance, right now when I started a program several times in a row I got numbers all in the 23000 range for example as the first number. After that the numbers are more random. I've always just discarded the first rand() number like you mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure it's the higher order bits that remain unchanged?  The book "Numerical Recipes in C" implies it's the other way around, i.e. the lower order bits are much less random.  The rand(3) man page (http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) actually quotes that book.

Comment: Void: Yes, I am aware that lower order bits are supposed to be much less random. However, in this particular case, I have found out that for the first number generated the opposite is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that rand() is not a very strong random number generator, the small amount of bias added by the standard approach is probably not an issue: (higher-lower) needs to be smaller than MAX_RAND of course.

```
lower + rand() % (higher-lower+1);
```

---

fixed off by one error.

Comment: `lower + rand() % (higher-lower+1);`

Comment: It would be `lower + rand() % (higher-lower + 1);`
Out of academic curiosity, I'd like to get a different solution to this problem, but thanks for your input. :)

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` is not a good random-number generator. In addition to the problem you observed it's period length can be very short.

Consider using one of the [`gsl` random number generators](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Generation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what OS your are using you may have `random()` available in addition to `rand()`. This generates much better pseudo-random numbers than `rand()`. Check `<stdlib.h>` and/or `man 3 random`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good, but you should substitute

```
lower + (int) upper * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
```

with

```
lower + (int) (upper - lower + 1)*(rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
```

The following code works nicely on my machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define lower 10
#define upper 20

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int number;

    srand(time(0));
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        number = lower + (int) (upper - lower + 1)*(rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        printf ("%d\n", number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, since `time(0)` gives the current time *in seconds*, two executions within the same second give the same result.

Comment: "rand() gives the current time in seconds" - That's an odd implementation. :P

Comment: @Bill: Oh, er, well... it's still an undocumented feature. Top secret. Don't tell anybody

Answer (score 1):

C++0x random number library (also available in TR1 and Boost) finally solves some nasty issues of rand. It allows getting real randomness (random_device) that you can use for proper seeding, then you can use a fast and good pseudo random generator (mt19937), and you may apply a suitable distribution to that (e.g. uniform_int for min-max range with equal probability for each value).

It also does not use global hidden state like rand() does, so there won't be any issues in multi-threaded programs.

Due to all the modularity it is a bit more difficult to use than simply calling rand, but still the benefits greatly outweigh the steeper learning curve.